# Jekyll Converter for R Markdown

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to write a Jekyll converter for R Markdown files. I created `RMarkdownConverter.rb` and placed it in my `_plugins` directory. I have verified that other plugins are working but this one is not. I also don't see any error messages, including the ones I put in myself. It seems this is not being used. However, Jekyll is generating an HTML file for my `.Rmd` file but simply processes the R chuck as code chuck. Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

`RMarkdownConverter.rb` file:

```
module Jekyll
    class RMarkdownConverter < Converter
        safe true
        priority :low

    def setup
      STDERR.puts "Setting up R Markdown..."
      return if @setup
      require 'rinruby'
      @setup = true
    rescue
      STDERR.puts 'do `gem install rinruby`'
      raise FatalException.new("Missing dependency: rinruby")
    end

        def matches(ext)
            ext =~ /Rmd/i
        end

        def output_ext(ext)
           '.html'
        end

        def convert(content)
      setup
      STDERR.puts "Using R Markdown..."
      R.eval "require(knitr)"
      R.eval "render_markdown(strict=TRUE)"
      R.assign "content", content
      STDERR.puts content
      R.eval "out <- knit(text=content)"
      R.eval "print(out)"
        end
    end
end
```

The contents of my first R Markdown post:

````
--- 
layout: post
title: Using (R) Markdown, Jekyll, and Github for Blogging
published: true
tags: R R-Bloggers Jekyll github
type: post
status: publish
---

First, we need to install [RinRuby](https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/) to call R from Ruby. In the terminal, execute:

    gem install rinruby

First R chuck:

```{r}
2 + 2
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the last few lines with the following

```
R.assign "content", content
R.eval "knitr::render_markdown(strict = TRUE)"
R.pull "(knitr::knit2html(text = content, fragment.only = TRUE))"
```

I think you need `R.pull` to copy the contents of R output to Ruby. Moreover, I would recommend directly converting from Rmd to html. I have used this strategy successfully in working with [Ruhoh](http://www.ruhoh.com) which is another ruby based blogging platform.

UPDATE. It is very odd but using the extension rmd seems to conflict with md. I changed it randomly to `ram` and jekyll seems to pick it up correctly. I am not sure why.

Comment: It also appears that if you add `markdown_ext: markdown` to `_config.yml` Jekyll will the process the `rmd` files. However, it also means that `md` files will not be processed. Not a big deal for me as I have been using `.markdown` file extensions.

Comment: There should be a way to do this without invoking `rinruby` which is known to be slow. I am exploring how to use a shell command directly to process Rmd files, however the backticks used by knitr trips up shell execution.